# How to correctly position image with css

Tags: html, css, cs-cart

I am working on a cs-cart site. I have a image with round circles. I then have other images that are round circles. I need to position the circle images over the first image circles. The problem is when I use position: absolute everything works great but when the browser changes resolutions the buttons move. when I use the position: relative the images stay in there place but the links do not work

Background Image

```
<p>
 <img src="http://thrivegoods.net/images/MAIN PAGES/menumainmarketplace.jpg" class="MenuMarketplaceBanner" style="background-color: initial;">
</p>
```

small circle  image

```
<p>
 <a href="http://thrivegoods.net/artist-info?action=preview"><img src="http://thrivegoods.net/images/MAIN%20PAGES/BUTTONS/roundinfoforartists.jpg" class="RoundInfoForArtists" alt="RoundInfoForArtists"></a>
</p>
```

css

```
.RoundAccountabilityButton {
 position: absolute;
  top: 1185px;
  left: 489px;
  z-index: 3;
 }

.MenuMarketplaceBanner {
 position: relative;
 z-index: 1;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

position absolute works fine when you give it the parameters fo where you want it to sit, like top right left bottom. But it will go out of the normal flow of your site when you use absolute. Can you supply your css to see it?

One way you can try is get a div, make it relative, so it is within the flow of your webpage then nest your images inside it. Make them absolute to the div (which is relative).

i think this might help your question, if it doesnt I can try again when I get to my pc and code it myself :)

UPDATE: Cant replicate the scenario on my PC, your links work just fine when resolution changes.

Comment: forgot to post the css! here you go

Comment: can you check out the actual site? http://thrivegoods.net/?store_access_key=testing   click on Marketplace Info. images are at the bottom of the screen

Comment: I don't see an area saying 'market place info' to click on, however i do like your little back to top button that pops out of the screen. That looks dead nice on screen.

Comment: im still looking through your site, goinf off comp now message me will be back on in a few hours this evening. have you considered using em or % size instead of pixel size? works better when changing different resolutions